# Circles aren't updating in a multiline graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3.js multiline graph with circles added on every path peak. When I update my graph, the paths update just fine with the new data but the circles don't seem to get updated at all. Here's my code: http://jsbin.com/eMuQOHoV/3/edit

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the data point circles in the same way that you've created them. In particular, you're using a nested selection when creating them, but not when updating. This means that the data won't get matched correctly on update and nothing happens.

The code for the update should look like this.

```
var sel = svg.selectAll('.series')
             .data(sources);

sel.select('path')
   .transition()
// etc

// update circles
sel.selectAll('.datapoint')
   .data(function (d) {
     return d.values;
   })
// etc
```

Complete jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/awuFOsu/1/edit).